# Getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'" when calling seaborn.heatmap()

Tags: python, matplotlib, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to run some Python code on a **Jupyter Notebook**, but when I call the `seaborn.heatmap()` method to plot a confusion matrix I get the `AttributeError`. Here's the **code** throwing the error:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(conf_matrices[j], annot=True, cmap='Blues')
```

Here's the **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/IMUSensorsRecognizer/source-files/Main.py", line 334, in <module>
    show_and_save_images(save, scores, confusion_matrices, params, test_sizes,
  File "/content/IMUSensorsRecognizer/source-files/Main.py", line 93, in show_and_save_images
    ax = sns.heatmap(conf_matrices[j], annot=True, cmap='Blues')
  File "/usr/local/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py", line 550, in heatmap
    ax = plt.gca()
  File "/usr/local/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2274, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 867, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/local/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 812, in figure
    fig = manager.canvas.figure
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'canvas'
```

Here's how `conf_matrices` is calculated:

```
for i in range(tries):
    if i in scores.keys():
        conf_matrices[i] += classifier.classify(model_type, i)
    else:
        conf_matrices[i] = classifier.classify(model_type, i)
```

Where the method `classify(model_type, i)` returns this:

```
return skm.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Here's how `conf_matrices[j]` looks like when printed:

```
[[3091 2152  581   70  276]
 [1741 3454  491  122  255]
 [ 721  716 4330   60  382]
 [ 231  344  261 3198  281]
 [ 878  429  539   67 1131]]
```

So, it seems like the object 'manager' is `None` for some reason.
It's strange because the same code works fine when run in **Intellij IDEA**, but not in the **Jupyter Notebook** on Google Colab (I use the same versions of **matplotlib 3.5.2** and **seaborn 0.11.2**).

The Jupyter Notebook **cell** is the following:

```
%%bash
ls
source activate py39
python --version
cd ~/../content/IMUSensorsRecognizer
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install ipykernel 
cd source-files
ls

python Main.py rf 50 0.75 1 5 4 7 24 t f
```

Does someone know why this error is thrown? **Thank you** in advance.

**EDIT**:
The issue persisted even after disconnecting from the Google Colab session, deleting all the data and reconnecting. It was solved a couple of days after, when the Google Colab machine changed. So, probably the issue was due to the Google Colab machine in use.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code (especially how `conf_matrices` is made)? I just tried briefly with a simple `confusion_matrix` from `sklearn.metrics` and it worked fine

Comment: Hi @MichaelS., thank you for your answer. I updated the question as you asked. As I mentoned, it all works fine with IntelliJ IDEA, but does not work on a Jupyter Notebook.